# Convert CT Slices to Planar X-Ray Image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, itk, medical, medical-imaging

I have axial slices of chest CT scans. Now, I want to use all these slices to construct a planar structure like an X-ray with a coronal view (Posterior to Anterior or Anterior to Posterior view).

I have no idea how to proceed with this problem. One way I think is a weighted average of the slices along the coronal plane with more weights to the frontal slices for AP view.

Please share your ideas on how to proceed with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`MeanProjectionImageFilter`](https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1MeanProjectionImageFilter.html) in SimpleITK.

I used 3D Slicer to download a sample chest CT and applied the filter using the `Simple Filters` module:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't even have to do any weighting. If you want something more advanced, you could go with [Siddon-Jacobs](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITKTwoProjectionRegistration/blob/master/test/GetDRRSiddonJacobsRayTracing.cxx) (see [discussion](https://discourse.itk.org/t/create-drr-image-from-chest-ct-scan/1370)) or something from [reconstruction toolkit](https://www.openrtk.org/).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a 2-d x-ray-like image from a 3-d CT volume, you can use ITK's MaximumProjectionImageFilter to do that.

Here's the documentation for the filter:

https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1MaximumProjectionImageFilter.html